# i have an error when executing "from lxml import etree" in the python command line after successfully installed lxml by pip

Tags: macos, python-2.7, lxml, llvm-gcc, elementtree

```
    bash-3.2$ pip install lxml-2.3.5.tgz 
    Unpacking ./lxml-2.3.5.tgz
      Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///Users/apple/workspace/pythonhome/misc/lxml-2.3.5.tgz
        Building lxml version 2.3.5.
        Building with Cython 0.17.
        Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.27
        Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib

        warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    Installing collected packages: lxml
      Running setup.py install for lxml
        Building lxml version 2.3.5.
        Building with Cython 0.17.
        Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.27
        Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib
        skipping 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'lxml.etree' extension
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/etree.so
        skipping 'src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'lxml.objectify' extension
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -w -flat_namespace
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/objectify.so

    Successfully installed lxml
    Cleaning up...
    bash-3.2$ python
    Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import lxml
    >>> import html
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named html
    >>> from lxml import html
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 12, in 
        from lxml import etree
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister
      Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

get same error again for older version lxml2.3.4

```
    bash-3.2$ pip install lxml-2.3.4.tgz 
    Unpacking ./lxml-2.3.4.tgz
      Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///Users/apple/workspace/pythonhome/misc/lxml-2.3.4.tgz
        Building lxml version 2.3.4.
        Building with Cython 0.17.
        Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.27
        Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib

        warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    Installing collected packages: lxml
      Running setup.py install for lxml
        Building lxml version 2.3.4.
        Building with Cython 0.17.
        Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.27
        Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/local/lib
        skipping 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'lxml.etree' extension
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/etree.so
        skipping 'src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'lxml.objectify' extension
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -w -flat_namespace
        llvm-gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.objectify.o -L/usr/local/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/lxml/objectify.so

    Successfully installed lxml
    Cleaning up...
    bash-3.2$ python
    Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import os
    >>> import lxml
    >>> from lxml import etree
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister
      Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

Answer (score 1):

See also [get errors when import lxml.etree to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355984/get-errors-when-import-lxml-etree-to-python)

I think the key error here is this:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister
```

I found [another person with the same problem on an lxml dev list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.lxml.devel/6028).

Their suggestion:

You probably need to check your libxml/libxslt libraries. Make sure you have the versions required in the [lxml installation instructions](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

Start by running

```
ldd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

That will show if you have any unresolved shared libraries. You may need to install/update some packages.

Check the thread linked above for more troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've tried to use Conda environment and it worked. The default venv seems to work horribly on M1 silicon.

You will have to install via this conmmand:

```
conda install -c conda-forge requests-html
```