# error when installing LXML for Python on mac with OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: python, lxml

I can't manage to install LXML on a mac with OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite, in Python 2.7.9.

I run the magic command:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
```

suggested [here](http://roderickhodgson.com/blog/2012/10/27/building-python-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-dot-7/) and [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

but when I import lxml.html I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

similar problems also reported in other questions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355984/get-errors-when-import-lxml-etree-to-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358842/i-have-an-error-when-executing-from-lxml-import-etree-in-the-python-command-li)

I had no luck. I tried to reinstall everything but it always tell me

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried installing with `sudo pip install lxml`?

Comment: yes, sorry indeed it was: STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml
(edited)

Comment: Then you may try manually install from the source using `setup.py`.